# Converting from cryptopp::integer to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, crypto++, qtcore

How to convert from cryptopp::integer to QString?

If it's important I work on Mac OS.
I absolutely don't know what to do, only trying to use QCA, but it wasn't good enough!

Comment: GetBits() with BitCount() and then QString::number() seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you can deduce from the reverse - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398304/qt-and-cryptopp-converting-qstring-qchar-to-be-accepted-with-cryptopp

Comment: @Leeor yes, that is useful, but not enough fool solution.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I am weak in cryptopp and don't know this functions.But now I  try to realize you suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Leeor: how is that thread related? I understand it is the google result which comes up at the beginning, but that does not make it solve this issue. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp, where did I say it solves the issue? Just checked for dups (which it isn't)

Comment: @LaszloPapp I solved my problem. I think your way is the best way working with QString and cryptopp:integer. Thank you very much! You really help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback to my comment, it seems that you need three steps.

1) Call the `BitCount()` method to get the number of bits in the integer.

2) Then, you can get all the bits by using the `GetBits()` method.

3) Once that is done, you can call use the `QString::number() method to get the actual integer into the desired`QString` as the return value of the static method.

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert from cryptopp::integer to QString?

You could also do something like this:

```
CryptoPP::Integer i = 1;
i <<= 128;
i--;
i *= 3;

ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << i;

QString qs(oss.str().c_str());
```